# Mysql error unknown system variable 'servername'

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Hi I am trying to get the servername and instance to use in sqlcmd. I am trying to invoke the command

`select @@servername`

in MySQL 5.7 Command Line Client. But I'm getting the following error.

```
ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'servername'
```

does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: MySQL?  MySQL does not have a concept of `<servername>\<instancename>` nor a global variable called `@@SERVERNAME`. Also, I've never seen `sqlcmd` used with MySQL.  It sounds somewhat as if you are mixing things up between Microsoft SQL Server or another platform... and MySQL.

Comment: Re-tagged to include MSFT peeps

Answer (score 0):

i do not think `select @@servername` is a vliad command for mysql , if you want to know server details try :

```
SHOW VARIABLES;
```

Comment: I want to run `sqlcmd -S <servername>\<instancename> -U "root" -P "pass" -i "D:\MySql\mysql2.sql"` but servername and instancename do not appear in the mysql variables list. how do i execute this command?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's nothing in `servername`. Are you trying to get `server_id`?

```
| secure_auth                                       | OFF                                                                                                                    |
| secure_file_priv                                  |                                                                                                                        |
| server_id                                         | 1                                                                                                                      |
| shared_memory                                     | OFF                                                                                                                    |
| shared_memory_base_name                           | MYSQL                                                                                                                  |
| skip_external_locking                             | ON                                                                                                                     |
| skip_name_resolve                                 | OFF                                                                                                                    |
| skip_networking                                   | OFF                                                                                                                    |
| skip_show_database                                | OFF                                                                                                                    |
| slave_compressed_protocol                         | OFF                                                                                                                    |
| slave_exec_mode                                   | STRICT                                                                                                                 |
| slave_load_tmpdir                                 | C:\WINDOWS\TEMP                                                                                                        |
| slave_net_timeout                                 | 3600                                                                                                                   |
| slave_skip_errors                                 | OFF                                                                                                                    |
| slave_transaction_retries                         | 10                                                                                                                     |
| slave_type_conversions                            |                                                                                                                        |
| slow_launch_time                                  | 2                                                                                                                      |
| slow_query_log                                    | OFF                                                                                                                    |
| slow_query_log_file                               | c:\Wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\data\Praveen-Kumar-slow.log                                                              |
| socket                                            | /tmp/mysql.sock                                                                                                        |
| sort_buffer_size                                  | 524288                                                                                                                 |
| sql_auto_is_null                                  | OFF                                                                                                                    |
| sql_big_selects                                   | ON                                                                                                                     |
| sql_big_tables                                    | OFF                                                                                                                    |
| sql_buffer_result                                 | OFF                                                                                                                    |
| sql_log_bin                                       | ON                                                                                                                     |
| sql_log_off                                       | OFF                                                                                                                    |
| sql_low_priority_updates                          | OFF                                                                                                                    |
| sql_max_join_size                                 | 18446744073709551615                                                                                                   |
| sql_mode                                          |                                                                                                                        |
| sql_notes                                         | ON                                                                                                                     |
| sql_quote_show_create                             | ON                                                                                                                     |
| sql_safe_updates                                  | OFF                                                                                                                    |
| sql_select_limit                                  | 18446744073709551615                                                                                                   |
| sql_slave_skip_counter                            | 0                                                                                                                      |
| sql_warnings                                      | OFF                                                                                                                    |
| ssl_ca                                            |                                                                                                                        |
| ssl_capath                                        |                                                                                                                        |
| ssl_cert                                          |                                                                                                                        |
| ssl_cipher                                        |                                                                                                                        |
| ssl_key                                           |                                                                                                                        |
| storage_engine                                    | InnoDB                                                                                                                 |
| stored_program_cache                              | 256                                                                                                                    |
| sync_binlog                                       | 0                                                                                                                      |
| sync_frm                                          | ON                                                                                                                     |
| sync_master_info                                  | 0                                                                                                                      |
| sync_relay_log                                    | 0                                                                                                                      |
| sync_relay_log_info                               | 0                                                                                                                      |
| system_time_zone                                  | GMT Standard Time                                                                                                      |
```

Comment: I want to run sqlcmd -S <servername>\<instancename> -U "root" -P "pass" -i "D:\MySql\mysql2.sql" but servername and instancename do not appear in the mysql variables list. how do i execute this command?